# Is there a specific way to input characters at the beginning of a new line?

Tags: python, string, formatting

Current I am trying to implement a way to input ">" at the beginning of each separate line in a string.

An example would be:

String:

```
"Hello how are you!

 Python is cool!"
```

Now that's all one big string, with a line break. But is there a function to establish when and where the line break is? For as I stated above, I'd like to incorporate a ">" at the beginning of each new line. Like so:

String:

```
">Hello how are you!

 >Python is cool!"
```

*Note: The string isn't permanently set, so that's why I am having to work around this.*

---

Hopefully that makes sense, and thanks for your help!

Comment: So your string is : `'Hello how are you!\n\nPython is cool'`

Comment: Yes technically it is @MalikBrahimi, though it's set up like: '''Hello how are you! (line-break) Python is cool!'''

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just split the lines and concat:

```
lines = """Hello how are you!

 Python is cool!"""

for line in lines.splitlines():
    if line:
       print(">" + line)
    else:
        print(line)


>Hello how are you!

> Python is cool!
```

To get a new string and keep the newlines set keepends=True:

```
new_s = "".join([">{}".format(line) if line.strip() else line
             for line in lines.splitlines(True)])
print(new_s)
>Hello how are you!

> Python is cool!
```

**str.splitlines([keepends])**

> Return a list of the lines in the string, breaking at line boundaries. This method uses the universal newlines approach to splitting lines. Line breaks are not included in the resulting list unless keepends is given and true.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi, it is just a matter of using join and setting keepends=True

Comment: Yeah, I guess you've gotten it down. Personally, I use regex even when there's no need for it.

Comment: Thanks, this worked well! Though thank you all for the answers, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Use a regular expression to find groups of non-newline characters and insert a `>` character before:

```
new_string = re.sub(r'[^\n]+', '>\g<0>', old_string) # be sure to import re
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work exactly as `print` except for what you ask:

`def newprint(*args, **kwargs):
     to_print = " ".join([str(a) for a in args])
     print(">", "\n> ".join(to_print.splitlines()), **kwargs)`